# XQuery Type of value does not match

Tags: xquery

```
declare variable $fb := doc("factbook.xml")/mondial;
for $c in $fb//country
where ($c/encompassed/@continent = 'f0_119') and ($c/@population < 100000)
return concat('Country: ',$c/name, ', Population: ',$c/@population);
```

it returns:

```
  Type Error: Type of value '

()
' does not match sequence type: xs:anyAtomicType?
At characters 11681-11698
At File "q2_3.xq", line 4, characters 13-67
At File "q2_3.xq", line 4, characters 13-67
At File "q2_3.xq", line 4, characters 13-67
```

however, if i do not do a concat return, just name or population it will work, and most strange thing is i have another program :

```
declare variable $fb := doc("factbook.xml")/mondial;
for $c in $fb//country
where $c/religions = 'Seventh-Day Adventist'
order by $c/name
return concat('Country: ',$c/name, ', Population: ',$c/@population);
```

The return syntax is exactly same, however, it works.
Why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing an example of your data it's impossible to say for sure, but if `$c/name` returns more than one value, then your error would make sense. Do you have any results where there are more than one `name` element?

Comment: you are right, there are country/name , however, there are also country/city/name, so how should I modify it to make it only show country/name

Comment: @NeoZhang `country/city/name` would not be an issue. Try changing your return statement to `($c/name)[1]`.

Comment: @NeoZhang If this answers your question, please click the check icon to the left of this answer to mark it as accepted.